# Rebuilding an old VS 2008 web app in VS 2010 with Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, reportviewer

I'm having difficulty with a web app that was originally developed in VS2008 that includes Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms. In order to rebuild this app in VS2010 (which we're using now), I've deleted the references to the old ReportViewer (v9.0.0.0) and replaced them with references to version 10.0.0.0 (Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common and Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms). The web.config seems to have updated correctly, and I also have an AJAX reference on the .aspx page that I updated to 10.0.0.0. When I run the app in VS debug mode, the app works **perfectly**, but when I try to build, I get the following message:

"The type or namespace name 'Reporting' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft' (are you missing an assembly reference?)"

The namespace name "Reporting" **does** exist in the namespace "Microsoft" because I looked it up. The only reference to the "Reporting" namespace is in the AJAX register tag on the .aspx page, and this automatically updates the .aspx.designer script, where I get the error. 
I don't understand why it would work in debug mode, but it doesn't compile correctly.

Comment: Did you install ms report library on build server? As far as i remember, it is not bin deployable.

Answer (score 0):

The server the application lives on needs to be running .NET Framework 4.0. I ran into this issue a few months ago.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, and yes we have .NET 4.0 on the server. That's a good thing to look for, so I appreciate your input.

Comment: BTW I DID fix the problem. I have instructions on how I fixed it in case someone else encounters the same error, but I have to wait 8 hours to post to this site?!